# Arrays selective subtraction

Tags: python, arrays, subtraction

I have two arrays, array1 and array2. For every entry of array1, I want to find the closest number to it in array2 and I want to subtract it from the entry of array1.

Is there a way to do that without for loops?

This is what I have up to now:

```
def find_nearest(array, value):
    return array[(np.abs(array - value)).argmin()]

array1 = np.array([[10,2],[3,7]]) 
array2 = np.array([3,2]) 

for ix,iy in np.ndindex(array1.shape):
    array1[ix,iy] = abs(array1[ix,iy] - find_nearest(array2, array1[ix,iy]))

print(array1)
```

gives me

```
[[7 0]
 [0 4]]
```

Comment: Please show an attempt as a [mcve] and provide a complete problem statement. For example, what happens to `[10]` when `array2 = [11, 9]`? Also, you'll need to be more specific about "computationally efficient"--do you mean time complexity or actual CPU time? If the latter, please describe your environment, benchmark suite and describe why your current solution isn't efficient enough or what sort of runtime you want to achieve. Also see [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/). Why can't you use `for` loops? Please tag a language. Thanks.

Comment: I've edited the question. In the case you mentioned (item 10 for array2=[11,9]) it should take the first one. The computational efficiency I refer to here is the CPU time. I am using Jupyter notebook.